# Reduced CPU time because of additional code in Contiki

Tags: contiki

We have added custom code to run on Z1 motes, simulate everything in Cooja and are tracking power consumption using Powertrace.
Since we added additional code to run we would expect the power consumption to go up, but instead it goes down.
Based on the CPU Time reported by Powertrace the CPU seems to be idle for longer time periods.

So we have some questions for a better understanding:

1. When enabling Powertrace, will the CPU Time of custom code be tracked automatically?
2. Is it possible, that our code requires to many resources and Powertrace is thus not capable to report correctly?

Comment: To be sure, your CPU time actually decreases when the new functionality is turned on compared to the case when it's turned off?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is the thing that causes the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, all that I can say it's very strange indeed.